# Factory girl undefined variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I want to pass the `course` variable and create `User` to determine which course the user should get in.

Here is my factory girl's code.

```
factory :user_with_course do
  sequence(:account){|n| "user_#{n}"}

  ignore do
    course nil
  end

  after(:create) do |user|
    create(:character, user_id: user.id, course_id: course.id) if course
    user.save
  end
end
```

I call it by using

```
create_list(:user_with_course, 3, course: course)
```

Why I got this error

```
undefined local variable or method `course' for #<FactoryGirl::SyntaxRunner:0x007f9348750188>
```

I thought the `ignore` should avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#transient-attributes), this should work:

```
  transient do
    course nil
  end

  after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
    create(:character, user_id: user.id, course_id: evaluator.course.id) if evaluator.course
    user.save
  end
```